# Jquery $.post Issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to my post data to login.php page. But problem is `$.post()` not working. tell me the error of this code.

## /includes/login.page (this one is a lightbox)

```
<form id="forgot-username-form" method="post" >
                    <label id="email">Forgotten your username ?</label>
                    <input type="email" name="forgot_username" id="user-email" />
                    <input type="submit" name="forgot_username" value="Send"/>
                </form>
```

## /script/username.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#forgot-username-form").submit(function() {
    var email = $("#user-email").val();     
    alert(email);

    $.post("login.php",{email:email},function(result){
            alert(result);
    });     

});
});
```

## /login.php

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
}
```

help me to find a error of this code.

Comment: Now, your last edit, i.e. changing `$_GET` to `$_POST` in `login.php`, makes all answers incorrect.

Comment: @vinodadhikary - yes that was a mistake. I was trying using GET but same result found. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#forgot-username-form").submit(function(e) { //<--note the "e" argument
        e.preventDefault(); //<--you forgot this
        var email = $("#user-email").val();     
        alert(email);

        $.post("login.php",{email:email},function(result){
           alert(result);
        });     
        return false; //<--or you can use this
    });
});
```

And capture `$_POST`.

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])):
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
}
```

And if you want to use `$_GET` method then try it like,

**SCRIPT**

```
$.get("login.php",{email:email},function(result){
        alert(result);
});
```

**PHP Page** `login.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['email'])){
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    echo $email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try with `POST` Because you are using `$.POST` not `$.GET`

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
}
```

And also you need to prevent the submit action like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#forgot-username-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();     // Prevent Here
        var email = $("#user-email").val();     
        alert(email);

        $.post("login.php",{email:email},function(result){
            alert(result);
        });
        return false;     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correctly only change you need to make is in your script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#forgot-username-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var email = $("#user-email").val();     
  alert(email);

  $.post("login.php",{email:email},function(result){
         alert(result);
  });     

 });
});
```

add a parameter e for event in the submit function and prevent its default behaviour by e.preventDefault function.

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
$.post("login.php",{'email':email},function(result){
        alert(result);
});
```

Changed I have done : I have just quoted your **post data object's key**.
you were doing wrong by assigning your email value to your post data object.